# Convert to single line for each section

Tags: linux

I have data as shown below. I want to convert it to a single line
for each part (starting with #).

I want it as:

```
#6536  -  NEW [R]  -  *NONE*.
  communicationFailureEvent  -  SITE  -  MSC_MR1_B02_KBN1(55/JANPAT4-1/D311-CE/DEL-ODM_L): 55 SITE  -  15/04/2018  11:21:55.
  [0]  Last RSL Link Failure   -  FMIC  -  Critical -/-.
  Config Tag 1

#7811  -  NEW [R]  -  *NONE*.
  communicationFailureEvent  -  SITE  -  MSC_MR1_B17_KB3(8/PNB_3G/D323-CE/DEL-IBM_L): 8 SITE  -  25/04/2018  15:52:04.
  [0]  Last RSL Link Failure   -  FMIC  -  Critical -/-.
  Config Tag 3ed1

#5569  -  NEW [R]  -  *NONE*.
  communicationFailureEvent  -  SITE  -  MSC_MR1_B22_GZBD2(49/TRISHUL-APT_3G/D441-GZ/GZB): 49 SITE  -  23/06/2018  08:28:54.
  [0]  Last RSL Link Failure   -  FMIC  -  Critical -/-.
  Config Tag 86d217

#3369  -  NEW [R]  -  *NONE*.
  communicationFailureEvent  -  SITE  -  MSC_KB1_B13_KB2(19/KIRTI-NAGAR_3G/D342-EA/DEL): 19 SITE  -  30/06/2018  11:06:41.
  [0]  Last RSL Link Failure   -  FMIC  -  Critical -/-.
  Config Tag 82cb8c

#1641  -  NEW [R]  -  *NONE*.
  communicationFailureEvent  -  SITE  -  MSC_KB1_B06_KB1(27/MOTINAGAR-NW_3G/D342-EA/DEL): 27 SITE  -  30/06/2018  12:08:59.
  [0]  Last RSL Link Failure   -  FMIC  -  Critical -/-.
  Config Tag 8540f6
===========================================================
#6536 NEW [R]   *NONE*. communicationFailureEvent SITE   MSC_MR1_B02_KBN1(55/JANPAT4-1/D311-CE/DEL-ODM_L): 55 SITE 15/04/2018    11:21:55. [0]  Last RSL Link Failure    FMIC    Critical -/-.   Config Tag 1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please update your question with your working. https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Formatting is really catastrophic, please change it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's always groups of 5 lines:

```
paste -s -d '    \n' data
```

- `paste -s` concatenates all lines in a single file, inserting delimiters if specified with `-d`
- delimiters are a single characters, if there are several characters they are used in a round-robin fashion each time a line is appended

Comment: This is your answer [from under another question](https://superuser.com/a/1377307/432690). The right thing to do is to close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: Relevant Meta: [1](https://meta.superuser.com/q/11972/432690), [2](https://meta.superuser.com/q/7658/432690).